# Modal Logic: Proof that a Maximally Consistent Set is Complete

Tags: modal-logic

To understand the completeness proof for modal logic, I need to show that Maximally Consistent Sets are complete. A set  $\Sigma$ is consistent if $\Sigma \not \vdash \bot$. A consistent set is maximal if any set that has $\Sigma$ as a proper subset is inconsistent. The properity I have trouble proving is that a maximally consistent set is complete, i.e. that for  every formula $\varphi$, one of $\varphi \in \Sigma$ or $\neg\varphi\in \Sigma$.

Many people online claim that $\Sigma\cup\{\varphi\}\vdash \bot$ implies that $\Sigma\vdash\neg\varphi$. And if that is the case, then the proof is easy. But it sounds a lot like the deduction theorem, which I was told is not true for modal logic. Where it the case, one could prove that $\vdash \alpha \to \square\alpha$, which is clearly not true.

So, how does one prove the completeness of maximally ocnsistent sets?

Comment: Completeness for which system? Tableau calculus?

Comment: @lemontree In this case the deduction used is Kripke's logic $\mathbf{K}$. What completeness is for maximally consistent sets is explained in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, $\Sigma \cup \{\varphi\} \vdash \bot$ indeed implies that $\Sigma \vdash \lnot \varphi$. And it is indeed a version of the deduction theorem. However there are caveats:

1. Deduction theorem fails in modal logic if we allow the unrestricted use of the necessitation rule. In the classic modal logic $\mathbf{K}$, necessitation is only applied to *theorems*: From $\vdash \varphi$ infer $\vdash \square \varphi$. So we cannot prove $\vdash \varphi \rightarrow \square \varphi$. ([The obligatory link to the corresponding paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s11229-011-9905-9.pdf))
2. The notion of '$\varphi$ provable from $\Sigma$' in modal logic is a bit different from the one in propositional logic. When we write $\Sigma \vdash \varphi$, what we really mean is that $\exists \psi_1, ..., \psi_n \in \Sigma$: $\vdash \bigwedge_i \psi_i \rightarrow \varphi$, where $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$. Compare this to the definition for propositional logic: $\exists \psi_1, ..., \psi_n \in \Sigma$: $\bigwedge_i \psi_i \vdash \varphi$, where $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$.